# Copying cells using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want copy content of cells and make border around these. This is simple example:

[image: example]

I tried to write macro, which copy top value, marge lower cells and make borders:

[image: example2]

```
For i = 0 To M_NAME.find(What:="*", After:=M_NAME, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column 

            M_NAME.Offset(1, i) = M_NAME.Offset(0, i)
            M_NAME.Offset(1, i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            M_NAME.Offset(1, i).Font.Color = rgbWhite

            With M_NAME.Offset(1, i).Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Color = rgbWhite
                .Weight = 3
            End With
        Next i
```

M_NAME is reference to first top cell.

Comment: and what is your question/problem?

Comment: You don't indicate what your problem is.  But setting the border color and the font color to white won't show up on a white background (as seen in your image).

Comment: @KazJaw The boarders don't fill all marged cells (only 1 under marged cell have boarder)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I know, this is only example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source cells seem to already have the borders, so there is no need to create them again.
You also need to consider the problems involved with working with merged cells.  The Find method will only find the upper left cell of the merged area, so that will cause a problem with your code.

There is no need to copy cell by cell.

If you want to copy the first row, borders, merged cells, and all, you could use something like:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyRow()
    Dim rToCopy As Range, rDest As Range
    Dim M_NAME As Range

Set M_NAME = Range("M_NAME")
Set rToCopy = Range(M_NAME, Cells.Rows(M_NAME.Row).Find(what:="*", after:=M_NAME, _
    LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).MergeArea)

Set rDest = rToCopy.Offset(rowoffset:=1)
rToCopy.Copy rDest
End Sub
```